# WebApi 2 - RAM usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm running my web service on shared hosting which offers me up to 100MB RAM on Application Pool.
My web service has got about 12 controllers and uses async Entity Framework + uses Cache:
https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache

For test the service responds very small amount of data - for example list of 20 customers with theirs address and contact data, no images etc..

After start (first request) the web service uses up to 144MB RAM after another few requests it's about 250-350MB used RAM - than server recycles my service.

Is that normal RAM usage for this amount of data and controllers? Or is there a problem in optimalization?

I'm novice in WebApi and I'm working on my thesis, but I tried to use async acces to DB using Entity Framework etc..

EDIT: After I set 32bit mode on the server the RAM usage is about 100-130Mb which is noticeably better result  than before, but I'm still not sure if it's good result.

Here I include sample one of my controller for get all customers list:

```
    // READ ALL -GET
    // ROUTE /api/Customers/
    [HttpGet]
    [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 30, ServerTimeSpan = 86400)]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCustomers()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var customers = await db.Customers
                .Include(s => s.Address)
                .Include(s => s.Contact)
                .Include(s => s.Company).ToListAsync<Customer>();
            if (customers == null)
                return NotFound();

            List<CustomerViewModel> viewCustomers = new List<CustomerViewModel>();

            foreach (var c in customers)
            {
                CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel{
                    Id = c.CustomerId,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.SureName,
                    ICO = c.ICO,
                    Notes = c.Notes,
                    Street = c.Address.Street,
                    Number = c.Address.Number,
                    ZipCode = c.Address.ZipCode,
                    City = c.Address.City,
                    Country = c.Address.Country,
                    MobileAreaCode = c.Contact.MobileAreaCode,
                    MobileNumber = c.Contact.MobileNumber,
                    Email = c.Contact.Email,
                    TelephoneAreaCode = c.Contact.TelephoneAreaCode,
                    TelephoneNumber = c.Contact.TelephoneNumber
                };
                if (c.Company != null)
                    customer.CompanyId = (int)c.CompanyId;
                else
                    customer.CompanyId = -1;
                viewCustomers.Add(customer);
            }
            return Ok(viewCustomers);
        }
    }
```

Comment: 100MB of memory is nothing. A single web browser with 3-4 windows open is going to use 150-250MB. You can't run a website on 100MB of memory. You should be allocating 1GB at least for even a very simple website running on IIS.

Comment: I agree with @EkoostikMartin. Keep in mind that you're running the ASP.NET framework, there's going to be some (relatively small) overhead there regardless of how big your actual application is.

Comment: Why all the async stuff?

Comment: But I'm not running web site with images etc, just web service which gives me data from db in json to my android application. But I understand your point that the ASP.NET framework takes a lot of ram itself :-) I edited my post, after I set 32bit mode on server it's about 100-130MB RAM usage. I'm novice in WebApi and EF so I used async stuff to try speed up my service.. I'm not sure if it helped or not..

Comment: What do you mean you "set 32bit mode on server"? You rebuilt your MVC project into 32-bit assemblies? Also, you seem to arbitrarily determined that 100-130MB of RAM is too much memory for your service to use...what are you basing that conclusion on?

Comment: On my shared webhosting web site, in section for customers is option to set "Turn on 32bit regime" - that is what I did. I have no idea, if 130Mb is too much or not, this is the reason why I wrote this question. I paid to local provider for basic shared web hosting that has got only 100MB RAM Application Pool. Higher more expensive option has got 200MB another 500MB etc.. I just want to know if it amount of RAM usage is OK or there is any problem with optimalization which I can change because I did it wrong.